# Run php function on button click to download pdf

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, pdf, fpdf

I made an onclick event where on trigger, I need to run php function where I implemented fpdf so I can download pdf file.

The event is triggered and now I need to download pdf when that button is clicked.

I think the problem is with javascript as I am new in that area.

Button is triggered, it's working, but is is always opening a blank page. How I can fix js so it can download directly that pdf file?

```
<?php

require (get_template_directory() . '/assets/php/fpdf/fpdf.php');

function download(){
if (isset($_POST['download'])){

    $pdf = new FPDF();
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
    $pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');

    $rand = rand(1, 1000);

    $pdf->Output($rand . '.pdf', 'F');

  }
}
```

and js

```
function download() {
        $('.download').click(function() {
            var templateUrl = object_name.templatedir;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: templateUrl + '/includes/dompdf.php',
                success:function(url){
                    window.open(url, '_blank');
                },
            })
        });
    }
```

Comment: try replacing $pdf->Output('$rand.'.pdf','F'); on $pdf->Output($rand.'.pdf','D');

Comment: In your PHP Do you call your function anywhere? In other words where is the `download();` call

Comment: Do you call the javascript function `download()` anywhere?

Comment: I do. The function is triggered as it opens the blank window that is defined in it. @RiggsFolly

Answer (score 0):

You have one to many quotes on this line

```
$pdf->Output('$rand.'.pdf','F');
```

Try this

```
$pdf->Output($rand . '.pdf', 'F');
```

Also as you are setting a click handler I would not run it in a function, run it without the function wrapper to make sure it is run.

```
<script>
$('.download').click(function() {
    var templateUrl = object_name.templatedir;
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: templateUrl + '/includes/dompdf.php',
            success:function(url){
                window.open(url, '_blank');
            }
    })
});
</script>
```

And you dont appear to run the PHP Function, so either add a call or dont put that code in a function

```
<?php

require (get_template_directory() . '/assets/php/fpdf/fpdf.php');

function download(){
    if (isset($_POST['download'])){

        $pdf = new FPDF();
        $pdf->AddPage();
        $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
        $pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');
    
        $rand = rand(1, 1000);
    
        $pdf->Output($rand . '.pdf', 'F');
    }
}

download();
```

Personally I would do it without the function wrapper as

```
require (get_template_directory() . '/assets/php/fpdf/fpdf.php');

if (isset($_POST['download'])){

    $pdf = new FPDF();
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
    $pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');

    $rand = rand(1, 1000);

    $pdf->Output($rand . '.pdf', 'F');
}
```

Because of LAST Comment

Then you need to pass the `download` parameter on yrou ajax call

```
<script>
$('.download').click(function() {
    var templateUrl = object_name.templatedir;
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: {download:1},
            url: templateUrl + '/includes/dompdf.php',
            success:function(url){
                window.open(url, '_blank');
            }
    })
});
</script>
```

Comment: I did. Still blank. @RiggsFolly

Comment: I removed functon part, still the same. @RiggsFolly

Comment: Thank you so much and I think it's woking but I keep getting mistake: Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'download' not found or invalid function name in /var/www/html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 287
@RiggsFolly

Comment: Well that means you have something that is calling the PHP `download()` function, so you can put it back into the function wrapper

Comment: PS: Always better to tell us this is WordPress if it is

Comment: Lol, sorry, it is. When I remove isset it's working. It automatically generates pdf but when I put back isset part in php func it opens blank page?  @RiggsFolly